# Sphinx won't update from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sphinx

My Sphinx server was working to a greater or lesser extent using mySQL. The system I need to integrate into, however, is using SQL Server. Upon changing the config as below, changes aren't being brought over.

Is this because documents that have been changed in SQL Server can't override existing records in Sphinx or some other reason? Thanks.

Snippet of sphinx.conf.dist

```
source src1
{
    # data source type. mandatory, no default value
    # known types are mysql, pgsql, mssql, xmlpipe, xmlpipe2, odbc
    type            = odbc

    #####################################################################
    ## SQL settings (for 'mysql' and 'pgsql' types)
    #####################################################################

    # some straightforward parameters for SQL source types
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = test
    sql_pass        = test123
    sql_db          = test
    sql_port        = 1433  # optional, default is 3306
```

Comment: The `host`/`user`/`pass` settings are ignored if you use `type=odbc`. You need to use the [`odbc_dsn` setting](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-odbc-dsn). Configuring ODBC can be a bit of a drag -- your first priority should be to read the error logs, because without those you'll never be able to tell what's wrong. It should currently not be connecting to the server at all, and give an error about how `src1` is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "odbc_dsn" setting as suggested by Jeroen led me down the correct path to configuring the settings correctly.